Why oject property express-validator changed
Property Object change when I used in Array
I had object property types validationChain Object Validator. And I have two array use this obj Two array. I want to know that, why property of this obj had changed. Example, 'Title' not have .NotEmpty but after Array one this have .NotEmpty

Help us help you - Please include a [mcve] as formatted text, not an image
